# What are the standard approaches to authorisation and syncing of a local Android DB to a server

Tags: android, database, authentication, synchronization, android-contentprovider

I am new to Android and am about to write an application that allows a user to edit some data offline and then sync it to a master database on a server somewhere when online.

I am assuming that in order for the user to be able to work offline, I will need to have a database on the Android device which can be updated via a content provider / database adapter class.

My question is, what are my high level options for authenticating and synchronising my local database with the server database? Are there any common/recommended approaches?. I have heard of using RESTful APIs on the Server (but I do not know much about them) - is this a standard approach?.

Also, is there a common approach to how often the sync is done - e.g. periodically? immediately upon a change when online?.

Any help would be much appreciated as this is very much a grey area for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a little hard to answer all these questions since it really depends upon the application and how you want it to work.  But, I would definitely look into RESTful web services.  There are a number of good tutorials about this on the web, but basically you have to set up a Web Server that can take parameters in the URL and sometimes data in the body of a POST.  For your case it will likely be a POST with data so you can send the update to the DB.

But, there are some other problems, of course synching has to be done both ways.  What if the data was changed on both the server and the mobile client?  How do you do conflict resolution there?

Second, as to the question of how often to sync - that is really up to you and how time critical is the data.  Of course the longer you wait between syncs, the more stale the online data will be and the more likely it will be modified in both places.  Syncing periodically is probably a good start and then adding in the sync when connectivity is back if you find that several sync periods have gone by without being able to connect - like if the phone is in airplane mode for example.  But when syncing periodically, you need to be very mindful of data usage and battery so select a period that is reasonable - perhaps once an hour?  And only sync if changes were made.

Sorry I don;t feel like I can give more detailed info without knowing your actual use case for the data.

Comment: Thanks Kaediil. So, is RESTful web services the most common approach?

Comment: That is both the easiest and most used that I have seen.  Other options are full SOAP WebServices which is pretty heavyweight for mobile, or even direct connection to the DB, but across the internet, that is a huge security risk.  Use REST and JSON for responses rather then XML again due to it being lighter then XML and can be easily parsed in Java.

Comment: Thank you - that is very useful. I had a gut feeling that REST with JSON is the right way for me to go, but due to my lack of experience I  wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Kaediil - on the Android side of things I was thinking of going with a SyncAdapter and ContentProvider - would you recommend this?.

Comment: You can certainly do that, but a syncadapter will require you to create a new Account type on the Android device.  I personally have not done that because I always fetched data when the app was run by a user rather then constantly updating the data on the device.  If you have not seen this already, take a look at this including the video from Google IO 2010. http://naked-code.blogspot.com/2011/05/revenge-of-syncadapter-synchronizing.html

Comment: One last thing.  Unless you are collecting data when the user is not using the app and having to upload that new data to the server, a sync adapter might be overkill.  If you can only create new data to be synced during the app running, I would just use a background service to sync once your user has entered some new data, kinda like Facebook uploads photos for example.  Alos, if you need to notify the device of new data form the server when the app is not running, look at Google Cloud Messaging or GCM.